# Is there any easy and efficient way to write this code block which I am using to convert the Date and time to Timestamp in Groovy

Tags: groovy, timestamp

```
String date = parameters.sendDate;
String time = parameters.sendTime;
SimpleDateFormat date12Format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
SimpleDateFormat date24Format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String convertedTime = date24Format.format(date12Format.parse(time));
String convertedDate = UtilDateTime.toTimestamp(date , convertedTime);
```

//Currently this one is working but is there any much compact and easy way?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with much less code. I used 11PM to illustrate getting it to 24 hour format:

```
String sometime = '11:55 PM'
assert Date.parse('hh:mm a', sometime).format("HH.mm") == '23.55'
```